# Not able to parse json file and display data - react native

Tags: json, parsing, react-native, fetch

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import Button from 'react-native-button'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Home from './Home'

export class Temp extends Component{
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {
    data: '',
    textinput:'',
  }
   state={
            shouldShow: false
        }
}

    componentDidMount(){
    this._onPressButtonGET();
  } 

      _onPressButtonPOST(){
        fetch("url", {
            method: "POST",  
             headers: { 
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "entryDate":"3/2/2017 2:00 AM", 
                "systol": this.state.textinput,
                "mobileType":"ANDROID",
                "userName":"menutest",

               })})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            Alert.alert(
                "Blood pressure data",
                "Blood pressure data - " + JSON.stringify(responseData)
            )
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        })
        .done(); 
    }

    _onPressButtonGET(){
        fetch("url", {
            method: "POST",
             headers: {
                 'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             },
            body: JSON.stringify({"mobileType":"ANDROID","userName":"menutest"})})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => { 

                this.setState({ data : JSON.stringify(responseData)})

            }) .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })

       .done();
    }
    render(){
        return(

            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonPOST.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>Add</Text> 
                </TouchableHighlight>

            <TouchableOpacity style= {{left:300,top:-20, }}
 onPress={()=>{ this.setState({ shouldShow: !this.state.shouldShow })}}
><Text>Edit</Text></TouchableOpacity>

{this.state.shouldShow ? <TextInput placeholder='systol' 
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({textinput: text})}
           /> : null}

                 <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButtonGET.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>show</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>

                <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>  
            </View>
    );
    }
}


module.exports = Temp;
```

I need to parse json file and display the data that is entryDate and systol. but i am not able to parse it. but in the above code i am able to display all the data.

```
{
"List": [
  {
"entryDate": "03/02/2017",
"entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",
"entryTime": "2:00 AM",
"systol": "120"
},
  {
"entryDate": "03/02/2017",
"entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",
"entryTime": "2:00 AM",
"systol": "121"
},
  {
"entryDate": "03/02/2017",
"entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",
"entryTime": "2:00 AM",
"systol": "120"
},
  {
"entryDate": "03/02/2017",
"entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",
"entryTime": "2:00 AM",
"systol": "122"
},
  {
"entryDate": "03/02/2017",
"entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",
"entryTime": "2:00 AM",
"systol": "123"
}
]
}
```

this is my json file.

and i want output like:

```
entryDate:03/02/2017
systol:120
entryDate:03/02/2017
systol:121
entryDate:03/02/2017
systol:122
entryDate:03/02/2017
systol:123
```

Answer (score 0):

set data state to null

```
this.state = {
  data: null
};
```

change

```
this.setState({ data : JSON.stringify(responseData)})
```

to

```
this.setState({ data : responseData })
```

Then display relevant data inside your render like this -

```
  <View>
    ....
    ....
    {this.state.data &&
      this.state.data.List.map((d,i) => (
        <View key={i}>
          <Text>{d.entryDate}</Text>
          <Text>{d.systol}</Text>
        </View>
    ))}
  </View>
```

Comment: getting error "undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.data.List.map)

Comment: I made few edits to my answer. Check and try again. If it still doesn't work then show me the output of `console.log(this.state.data)` inside `render` function.

Comment: u mean output of this "<Text>{this.state.data}</Text> "'?

Comment: that is displaying all my json data {"List": [  {"entryDate": "03/02/2017", "entryDateTime": "03/02/2017 2:00 AM",.........]}     like this

Comment: You did not remove `JSON.stringify`. Read my answer again.

Comment: console.log(this.state.data) must be wrapped in an explicit <Text> component, this is the error i am getting now.

Comment: do `console.log` before `return`

Comment: console.log(this.state.data) i used this inside _onPressButtonGET(), but it is not displaying anything.

Comment: "do  console.log before return " this i did not understand.